# Custom Spinner with white text color

Tags: android, android-widget, android-spinner

I want my Action Bar spinner to display it's text in white (like in google maps app),
but i'm struggling to get there..

i'm trying something like this:

```
   <style name="Mepo.Spinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
   <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/StandardSpinnerItem</item>  
   <item name="spinnerItemStyle">@style/StandardSpinnerItem</item>
   </style>

  <style name="StandardSpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
  <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:color/white</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>
```

but that has no effect.
I know this his probably been asked but i can't find the right solution.
any ideas?
p.s i'm actually using sherlock action bar if that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end this is what i did, maybe this will help someone:

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/xxx.ActionBar.DropDown.Style</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/xxx.ActionBar.DropDown.Style</item>
    </style>
   <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">#0B2F39</item>
        <item name="android:background">#0B2F39</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">#0B2F39</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">#0B2F39</item>
    </style>

    <style name="xxx.ActionBar.DropDown.Style" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs__spinner_ab_holo_dark</item>
    </style>
```

if you have any remark or corretions i would love to hear them

Comment: How can this be an accepted answer to the OP's question? The text color is set nowhere, only background color.

Answer (score 1):

If you already use an custom theme(you extended the base theme and customized it) and you want to customize the spinner only for one activity you need to do this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
... your other items
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyTheme.Spinner" parent="Theme.MyTheme">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem</item>
</style>

<style name="Spinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem</item>
</style>    
<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
<style name="SpinnerItem.DropDownItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And to use this style in an activity use this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme.Spinner"  >
</activity>
```

If you want to customize the spinner for all the activities(your application) move the items from `Theme.MyTheme.Spinner` into `Theme.MyTheme`:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
   ... your other items
   <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
   <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem</item>
</style>
```